# Merge [vc6] and [visual-studio-6]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request, ambiguous-tags

We have two different tags for the same subject.

I suggest that questions currently tagged with [vc6](/questions/tagged/vc6) be changed to [visual-studio-6](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-6) to be consistant with the other Visual Studio tags. This ought to be make the questions easier to find.

Answer (score 3):

While a great number of those questions are about Visual C++ 6, not all of them are. Some of them are about Visual Basic 6, for example. I think it would be a better approach to remove the [visual-studio-6](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-6) tag from questions that are tagged [vc6](/questions/tagged/vc6) and are not about how to work Visual Studio at all, but are about language issues, MFC classes, and availability of DLLs.